# How to select ALL columns with Work Item Query Language (WIQL)?

Tags: azure-devops, workitem, wiql

I am trying to export all work items, and related data, from an Azure DevOps project. I am using Work Item Query Language (WIQL) but have no luck.

SELECT *
FROM... etc

Does not work. Any answers, thoughts, or suggestions?

Comment: You can't use wildcards. WIQL isn't SQL, it's just syntactically similar.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned, we cannot use wildcards in WIQL, it's not like SQL.

We have to specific either the friendly name or reference name of the fields to return the corresponding values. See [Limits on WIQL length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#limits-on-wiql-length) for details.

Actually, not all fields are required in general product scenarios, and the WIQL has the length limits. However, if you want to select all fields, then you can try to get all the available fields by calling [Fields - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API, then specify them in your WIQL.